# Timer not re-setting even after clicking the reset button

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to create a timer where I created 3 button:-

1. Start
2. Pause
3. Re-set

Everything is working fine except the re-set button. My aim to reset the timer from 0 after clicking the reset button, but it's starting from the time where it was paused.

Below is the code I created :-

```
# importing libraries
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys
import datetime
import time

start = datetime.datetime.now()  
  
class Window(QMainWindow):
  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
  
        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("Python Stop watch")
  
        # setting geometry
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 500)
  
        # calling method
        self.UiComponents()
  
        # showing all the widgets
        self.show()
  
    # method for widgets
    def UiComponents(self):
  
        # counter
        self.count = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(0,0,0)
  
        # creating flag
        self.flag = False
  
        # creating a label to show the time
        self.label = QLabel(self)
  
        # setting geometry of label
        self.label.setGeometry(75, 100, 250, 70)
  
        # adding border to the label
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border : 4px solid black;")
  
        # setting text to the label
        self.label.setText(str(self.count))
  
        # setting font to the label
        self.label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 25))
  
        # setting alignment to the text of label
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
  
        # creating start button
        start = QPushButton("Start", self)
  
        # setting geometry to the button
        start.setGeometry(125, 250, 150, 40)
  
        # add action to the method
        start.pressed.connect(self.Start)
  
        # creating pause button
        pause = QPushButton("Pause", self)
  
        # setting geometry to the button
        pause.setGeometry(125, 300, 150, 40)
  
        # add action to the method
        pause.pressed.connect(self.Pause)
  
        # creating reset button
        re_set = QPushButton("Re-set", self)
  
        # setting geometry to the button
        re_set.setGeometry(125, 350, 150, 40)
  
        # add action to the method
        re_set.pressed.connect(self.Re_set)
  
        # creating a timer object
        timer = QTimer(self)
  
        # adding action to timer
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
  
        # update the timer every tenth second
        timer.start(100)
  
    # method called by timer
    def showTime(self):
  
        # checking if flag is true
        if self.flag:
  
            # incrementing the counter
            #self.count+= 1
            self.elapsed_seconds = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
            self.hour = int(self.elapsed_seconds // 3600)
            self.min = int(self.elapsed_seconds % 3600 // 60)
            self.seconds = int(self.elapsed_seconds % 60)
            self.count ='{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(self.hour, self.min, self.seconds)
            
  
        # getting text from count
        text = str(self.count)
  
        # showing text
        self.label.setText(text)
        
  
    def Start(self):
        # making flag to true
        self.flag = True
        
  
    def Pause(self):
  
        # making flag to False
        self.flag = False
  
    def Re_set(self):
  
        # making flag to false
        self.flag = False
  
        # reseeting the count
        self.count = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(0,0,0)
  
        # setting text to label
        self.label.setText(str(self.count))
    
  
# create pyqt5 app
App = QApplication(sys.argv)
  
# create the instance of our Window
window = Window()
  
# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

I checked on the internet but found nothing. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: A suggestion: avoid commenting *every single line of code*. It's not only quite useless (most code is self explanatory, and writing "making flag to True" above `self.flag = True` makes absolutely no sense) but very distracting and annoying, making your code difficult to read. Use comments only when they are *actually* useful.

Answer (score 1):

To make the countdown start from 0 and not from the current time, you need to update the value of `start` variable.

1. Move start variable to constructor

```py
def __init__(self):
     ...
     self.start = datetime.datetime.now()
     ...
```

2. Update value of this variable on reset button click

```py
def Re_set(self):
     ....
     self.start = datetime.datetime.now()
     ...
```

3. Add this variable to showTime method

```py
def showTime(self):
     if self.flag:
         self.elapsed_seconds = (datetime.datetime.now() - self.start).total_seconds()
         ...
     ...
```